# Как можно настроить роутинг по подпапкам?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, rewrite, iis-7

Мне надо реализовать такую структуру.

```
sitename.com —> root/folder1
sitename.com/url1 —> root/folder2
sitename.com/url2 —> root/folder3
```

Сейчас конфигурация такая

```
<rule name="rootFolder1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^.*$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder1/{R:0}" />
</rule>

<rule name="rootfolder2" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^url1.*$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder2/" />
</rule>

<rule name="rootfolder3" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^url2.*$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder3/" />
</rule>
```

Файлы js и css в folder2 и folder3 не работают, они берутся из folder1. Как это можно реализовать на IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение:

```
 <rule name="rootfolder2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="url1(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder2/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rootfolder3" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="url2(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder3/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rootfolder1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder1/{R:0}" />
```

Спасибо за ответ [lex-li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li)!